# Audio parameters

Tags: android, audio

What are the fundamental parameters for audio?

For eg: Sampling rate,buffer,bit rate

What all does android media api supports?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are two essential parameters for audio :  sample_rate and bit depth

Answer (score -2):

There are four kind of sound setting in android 1)Alarm 2)Music 3)Ring Tone 4)Notification First Create object of AudioManager amanager; IF you want to set Volume use this code

For Notification

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Alerm

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Music

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Ring Tone

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

// Add new file to your media library
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

// Notifiy the media application on the device
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
```

Comment: :BTW,thanks for answering but read my question,i was talking about general audio parameters and also what all parameters that support android.